# Express JS, making more than 2000 requests throws "CONNECTION REFUSED" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, connection-pooling

I have created express application, with a lot of pages. I wanted to test one of my routes:

```
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {

   // some logic
});
```

To test this method I use `jMeter` application which makes 2000 requests to this route.

When I start test I have a lot of that kind of errors:

```
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.ConnectException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Connection refused: connect
```

Some requests pass and respond with correct result, but a lot of requests just can't connect. It failes more than half of these requests

Do I need to add some kind of configurations for my express app? Not being able to handle 2000 requests is not good even for minimum requirements i think.

Comment: 2000 requests in lets say 1 or 2 seconds is too much. It amounts to 86 million hits a day. A simple system cannot process this.

Comment: @kawadhiya21 I made ramp-up period 20 seconds, it's still failing half of them. How many requests in second is considered normal human behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [clustering](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html). Also if there are database calls, use mysql pool.